# Data Structures for BST where size uniquely determines shape

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

There are several data structures in which the number of elements uniquely determines the shape.
Examples would be binary heaps, arrays, lists, Braun trees, and Merkle mountain ranges.

Are there any such data structures that can be used to efficiently implement a binary search tree with good insertion/deletion performance?